# How to access the constructor type of an interface?

Tags: typescript

I know that we can directly access the property type of an interface with interfaceName['propertyName'], but how access the constructor?

Such as:

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
    new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;
}

class SomeNewClass<T> extends Promise<T> {
  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<PromiseConstructor['???']<T>>) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want that

```
constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<PromiseConstructor>) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the generic `T` of `PromiseConstructor` can not be known when `ConstructorParameters` tries to extract its arguments, just use:

```
class SomeNewClass<T> extends Promise<T> {

    constructor(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
        super(executor);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from `version 4.7.4` you can access the constructor by using `typeof`. Full example:

```js
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T> {

  constructor(...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof Promise<T>>) {
    super(...args);
  }

}
```

[Typescript playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeAFATgewLYEsIFMA8AKgHzQ4AeALjgHYAmMKG2%20x0A3gFAfTTCrUQKyAK7AKqZAAoAdLLDIA5hABc0AML9BIsRMTyw6HFWQQ8FeAAccqAGbRGWXISJEAlO249oEYVamzpeSVXAG5PAF8ucKA)

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, it's 100% the correct answer.
```ts
type PromiseExecutor<T> = ConstructorParameters<typeof Promise<T>>[0];
type PromiseResolver<T> = Parameters<PromiseExecutor<T>>[0];
type PromiseRejecter<T> = Parameters<PromiseExecutor<T>>[1];
```